# Binary Search Tree (BST) returning left child seen as function, don't understand

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, return, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to return a left child as a pointer

I have

```
 template <typename Type>
 class BSTNode {  
 private:
    int key;                                                             
    Type data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
}
```

And root

```
template <typename Type>
class BST {          
private:
   BSTNode<Type> *root; 
}
```

I absolutely need this, I can't find a way around it (not in the little time I have left)

```
this->root = auxRoot.getLeftChild();
```

here is getLeft

```
template <typename Type>
BSTNode<Type> *BSTNode<Type>::getLeftChild() {
return this->left();
}
```

Compiling error: `left cannot be used as a function`. Am I doing somethign wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`left` isn't a function, but a data member, so the parenthesis are illegal. It should be:

```
this->left;
```

Comment: I feel so awkward. Whenever I'm tired I just don't see these small stuff. Actually that's my main problem with c++, I miss a lot of `{};`.